# Search a Workbook, Then paste results on Search Page.

Tags: vba, excel

I posted this earlier this week, but I am finally done with it, and I am submitting it tomorrow. I wanted to get a final opinion/review from anyone on anything that could be refined.

This code searches a 8 page workbook. The first page of the workbook is the search page. It is where all of the results get posted. Also on this page you have a drop down menu. In that menu is each of the headers form the chart on the search page. You have the option to search through the entire workbook or you can choose a certain category. Results are then posted in the designated area shown in the picture below. And from there, you can print out all of those results.

[image: This is the Search Page]

Here is the Code.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    ComboBox1.Value = UCase(ComboBox1.Value)
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    UpdateSearchBox
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Select Case TextBox1.Value
        Case "F"
            TextBox1.Value = "G"
        Case "E"
            TextBox1.Value = "F"
        Case "D"
            TextBox1.Value = "E"
        Case "C"
            TextBox1.Value = "D"
        Case "B"
            TextBox1.Value = "C"
        Case "A"
            TextBox1.Value = "B"
        Case "G"
            TextBox1.Value = "A"
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    FindOne
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    UpdateSearchBox
End Sub

Sub UpdateSearchBox()
    Dim PageName As String, searchColumn As String, ListFiller As String
    Dim lastRow As Long

    If TextBox1.Value = "" Then
        PageName = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Select Case ComboBox2.Value
        Case "SEARCH ALL"
            searchRange = ("A:J")
        Case "EQUIPMENT NUMBER"
            searchColumn = "A"
        Case "EQUIPMENT DESCRIPTION"
            searchColumn = "C"
        Case "DUPONT NUMBER"
            searchColumn = "F"
        Case "SAP NUMBER"
            searchColumn = "G"
        Case "SSI NUMBER"
            searchColumn = "H"
        Case "PART DESCRIPTION"
            searchColumn = "I"
        Case ""
            MsgBox "Please select a value for what you are searching by."
    End Select

    With Sheets(PageName)
        lastRow = .Range(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

     If lastRow <> 0 And PageName <> vbNullString And searchColumn <> "" Then
        ListFiller = PageName & "!" & searchColumn & "2" & ":" & searchColumn & lastRow
        ComboBox1.ListFillRange = ListFiller
    End If
End Sub

Sub FindOne()

    Range("B19:J5000") = ""

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim k As Integer, EndPasteLoopa As Integer, searchColumn As Integer, searchAllCount As Integer
    Dim myText As String
    Dim totalValues As Long
    Dim nextCell As Range
    Dim searchAllCheck As Boolean

    k = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    myText = ComboBox1.Value
    Set nextCell = Range("B20")
    If myText = "" Then
        MsgBox "No Address Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Select Case ComboBox2.Value
        Case "SEARCH ALL"
            searchAllCheck = True
        Case "EQUIPMENT NUMBER"
            searchColumn = 1
        Case "EQUIPMENT DESCRIPTION"
            searchColumn = 3
        Case "DUPONT NUMBER"
            searchColumn = 6
        Case "SAP NUMBER"
            searchColumn = 7
        Case "SSI NUMBER"
            searchColumn = 8
        Case "PART DESCRIPTION"
            searchColumn = 9
        Case ""
            MsgBox "Please select a value for what you are searching by."
    End Select

    For I = 2 To k
        totalValues = Sheets(I).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim AddressArray(totalValues) As String

        If searchAllCheck Then
            searchAllCount = 5
            searchColumn = 1
        Else
            searchAllCount = 0
        End If

        For qwerty = 0 To searchAllCount
             If searchAllCheck Then
                Select Case qwerty
                    Case "1"
                        searchColumn = 3
                    Case "2"
                        searchColumn = 6
                    Case "3"
                        searchColumn = 7
                    Case "4"
                        searchColumn = 8
                    Case "5"
                        searchColumn = 9
                End Select
            End If

            For j = 0 To totalValues
                AddressArray(j) = Sheets(I).Cells(j + 1, searchColumn).Value
            Next j

            For j = 0 To totalValues
                If InStr(1, AddressArray(j), myText) > 0 Then
                    EndPasteLoop = 1
                    If (Sheets(I).Cells(j + 2, searchColumn).Value = "") Then EndPasteLoop = Sheets(I).Cells(j + 1, searchColumn).End(xlDown).Row - j - 1
                    For r = 1 To EndPasteLoop
                        Range(nextCell, nextCell.Offset(0, 8)).Value = Sheets(I).Range("A" & j + r, "I" & j + r).Value
                        Set nextCell = nextCell.Offset(1, 0)
                    Next r
                End If
            Next j
        Next qwerty
    Next I
    Debug.Print tc
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Sub CommandButton3_Click()

     Range("B19:J600000") = ""

     Range("B19:J5000").Select
     With Selection.Interior
         .Pattern = xlNone
         .TintAndShade = 0
         .PatternTintAndShade = 0
     End With

 End Sub

 Sub CommandButton4_Click()

 MsgBox ("!!!BE AWARE OF HOW MANY PAGES YOU ARE PRINTING!!!" & vbNewLine & "If it is too many, then refine your search to be more specific!")

 With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
     .Zoom = False
     .Orientation = xlPortrait
     .FitToPagesWide = 1
     .FitToPagesTall = 1

     ExecuteExcel4Macro ("PAGE.SETUP(,,,,,,,,,,,,{#N/A,#N/A})")
     If .Zoom < 30 Then
         .Zoom = 50
     Else
         .Zoom = False
         .FitToPagesWide = 1
     End If

 End With

 Range("B18:J" & Range("O24").Value).PrintOut Preview:=True

 End Sub


 Private Sub TextBox2_Change()

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an empty procedure:

> ```
>  Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
>
>  End Sub
> ```

---

I see you clearing ranges like this -

> ```
> Range("B19:J600000") = ""
> ```

Use the `.Clear` method

```
Range("B19:J600000").Clear
```

---

Here you use both `vbnullstring` and `""` -

> ```
> If lastRow <> 0 And PageName <> vbNullString And searchColumn <> ""
> ```

Stick with `vbnullstring`

---

You've got these

> ```
>   Dim k As Integer, EndPasteLoopa As Integer, searchColumn As Integer,
>   searchAllCount As Integer
> ```

as integers. Integers - [integers are obsolete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520). According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164506(v=office.10).aspx) VBA *silently* converts all integers to `long`.

---

A lot of your variable names are descriptive - great. Try [Standard VBA naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx) which have `camelCase` for local variables and `PascalCase` for other variables and names.

A boolean -

> ```
> Dim searchAllCheck As Boolean
> ```

is preferably named like a boolean

```
Dim isSearchAllCheck as Boolean
```

Otherwise, be sure to declare all your variables. When you don't define your variable, VBA will declare it as a *Variant* type that can hold any type of data. While this may be more flexible, it adds processing time to your macro as VBA decides or tests for the type. Additionally, since a Variant can be any type of data, you may miss out on valuable troubleshooting information on *Type Mismatch*

Always turn on `Option Explicit`. You can have it automatically by going to Tools -> Options in the VBE and checking the **Require Variable Declaration** option. This way if you have any variables not defined, the compiler will let you know.

---

> ```
> Select Case TextBox1.Value
>     Case "F"
>         TextBox1.Value = "G"
>     Case "E"
>         TextBox1.Value = "F"
>     Case "D"
>         TextBox1.Value = "E"
>     Case "C"
>         TextBox1.Value = "D"
>     Case "B"
>         TextBox1.Value = "C"
>     Case "A"
>         TextBox1.Value = "B"
>     Case "G"
>         TextBox1.Value = "A"
> End Select
> ```

What? Give this some context - right now it just looks meaningless.

On this one

> ```
> Case ""
>         MsgBox "Please select a value for what you are searching by."
> ```

Just use `Case Else`.

---

Consider giving your controls meaningful names. If `CommandButton4` is the *print button* go ahead and rename it as such.